# codeigniter issue in uploading csv file in cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, file-upload

I'm getting following  Error:
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
i want to upload csv file.

i'm using codeigniter file upload method do_upload
and i also supply allowed_types as csv

```
public function csvRateList(){
$redirectData=['error'=>'','success'=>''];

$type=$this->input->post('type');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$config['upload_path'] ='./csv/';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv'; //type of file

$config['max_size'] = '100';

$this->load->library('upload',$config);

$query = $this->db->get_where('csv_rate_list', array('type' => $type));

    if($query->num_rows()==0){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('rate_list', array('type' => $type));
            if($query->num_rows()==0){
            if($this->upload->do_upload()){
                $fdata=$this->upload->data();
                $newName=$fdata['file_name'];
                $origName=$fdata['orig_name'];
                $data = array(
                'type'      => $type ,
                'new_name'  => $newName ,
                'orig_name' => $origName,
                'timestamp' =>time()
                );
                $this->db->insert('csv_rate_list', $data); 
            }else{
                $redirectData['error']=$this->upload->display_errors();
                redirect(base_url().'add_rate');
            }
                $redirectData['success']='Successfully inserted!';
                $this->session->set_flashdata($redirectData);
                redirect(base_url().'add_rate');
            }else{
                $redirectData['error']='Service type already exists. in old table';
                $this->session->set_flashdata($redirectData);
                redirect(base_url().'add_rate');
            }
    }else{
        $record=$query->row_array();
        $id=$record['id'];
        $old_name=$record['new_name'];
        if($this->upload->do_upload()){
            $fdata=$this->upload->data();
            $newName=$fdata['file_name'];
            $origName=$fdata['orig_name'];
            $data = array(
            'type'      => $type ,
            'new_name'  => $newName ,
            'orig_name' => $origName,
            'timestamp' =>time()
            );
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('csv_rate_list', $data); 
            unlink('./csv/'.$old_name);
            $redirectData['success']='Successfully updated!';
            $this->session->set_flashdata($redirectData);
            redirect(base_url().'add_rate');
        }else{
            $redirectData['error']=$this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->session->set_flashdata($redirectData);
            redirect(base_url().'add_rate');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have your code enter into if($query->num_rows()==0){ loop??

Comment: check with condition $query->num_rows() > 0

Comment: This code is working fine on my local server xampp! There is only one problem with file type "csv" in cpanel

Comment: check permission of upload folder

Comment: any type of error it show??

Comment: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: have you try my solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77181/discussion-between-saty-and-daulat).

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify few line in (/system/libraries/Upload.php)

from:

```
$this->file_type = @mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']);
return;
```

to this:

```
$this->file_type = @mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']);
if (strlen($this->file_type) > 0) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the config/mimes.php have the correct value for "csv"

In $mimes array,find the 'csv' and check the following.

'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel'),

If not, add this into it.